# Why won't changes to SvgElements be visible when SvgDocument.Save() is called?

Tags: c#, svg, .net-core

SVG classes come from the vvvv/SVG library at https://github.com/vvvv/SVG

When attempting to modify the `.Content` values of an `SvgElement`, the changes are not rendered upon calling `SvgDocument.Save(graphic_object);`.

Is there a reasons that changes to `SvgElement.Content` wont properly render, while changes to other attributes such as `SvgElement.FontSize` will? Should I be using a different method to change the content of an `SvgElement` rather than directly modifying the content property?

Sample SVG XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<svg width="800" height="300" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

  <g>
    <title>Layer 1</title>
    <ellipse fill="#2c2f33" stroke-width="0" cx="649" cy="151" id="svg_7" rx="134" ry="134"/>
    <rect id="svg_6" height="268" width="470" y="17" x="194.5" stroke-width="0" fill="#2c2f33"/>
    <ellipse fill="none" stroke-width="11" cx="150" cy="150" id="svg_1" rx="134" ry="134" stroke="#ffffff"/>
    <line stroke="#ffffff" fill="none" stroke-width="11" stroke-opacity="null" fill-opacity="null" x1="149.5" y1="16" x2="657.82323" y2="16" id="svg_12"/>
    <line stroke="#ffffff" fill="none" stroke-width="11" stroke-opacity="null" fill-opacity="null" x1="149.5" y1="284.04663" x2="655.82327" y2="284.04663" id="svg_13"/>
    <path fill="none" stroke-width="11" stroke-opacity="null" fill-opacity="null" d="m654,16c84,0 130,71 130,134c0,62 -48,133 -130,134" id="svg_14" stroke="#ffffff"/>
    <text fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000" stroke-width="0" stroke-opacity="null" x="310" y="130" id="notice_type" font-size="94" font-family="Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif" text-anchor="start" xml:space="preserve" font-weight="bold" font-style="italic">notice type</text>
    <text stroke="#000" fill="#ffffff" stroke-width="0" stroke-opacity="null" x="520" y="210" id="notice_message" font-size="${font}" font-family="Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif" text-anchor="middle" xml:space="preserve" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal">username</text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Method I am using:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

using Svg;

    public static class SvgHandler
    {
        public static async  Task<MemoryStream?> GetWelcomeImage(bool welcome, string username)
        {
            try
            {
                // Load path
                var path = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Join("Resources", "Images", "welcome.svg"));
                // Load XML to File Stream
                using var fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

                // Create the new SVG Document
                var svg = SvgDocument.Open<SvgDocument>(fs);

                // Get the font size
                float font = username.Length <= 12 ? 44f : 44f - ((username.Length - 12f) * 1.1f);

                // Set the SVG properties to fill with custom content instead of placeholdres
                var title = svg.GetElementById("notice_type");
                title.Content = welcome ? "Welcome" : "Goodbye";

                var msg = svg.GetElementById("notice_message");
                msg.Content = username;
                msg.FontSize = new SvgUnit(font);

                // Get the graphics and Memory Stream objects
                using var map = new Bitmap(1000, 300);
                using var graphic = Graphics.FromImage(map);

                // Draw the SVG to the graphics object
                svg.Draw(graphic);

                // TODO: Draw the users profile picture

                // Save Graphic to new memory stream for sending purposes.
                MemoryStream? mem = new MemoryStream();
                map?.Save(mem, ImageFormat.Png);

                // Seek to beginning of file.
                mem?.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                return mem;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Program.Bot.Client.Logger.LogError(ex, "SVG Handler Failed");
                return null; 
            }
        }
```

**Notes:**

- When using Visual Studio to look at the values of the `SvgElement` and `SvgDocument` variables both show that the changes to `SvgElement.Content` have updated the `.Text` and `.Content` properties for the elements. This is looking at the values directly in the `SvgElement` and finding the `SvgElement` objects in the `SvgDocument`'s children.

Comment: I suspect .Content should be replaced by .Text i.e. title.Content becomes title.Text, and similarly for msg. If this is right I'll flesh it out into an answer.

Comment: I thought so too at first, but intellisense does not say .Text is an option (granted, thats not 100% but it usually means you cant interact with the property).

Comment: You need to cast it then i.e. ((SvgText)msg).Text =  ... or better, cast the result of GetElementById i.e. var title = (SVGText)svg.GetElementById("notice_type");